# Android Async task not working

Tags: android

I am calling this from a function by creating an object.The progress box appears and then disappears but the toast is not displayed.(I have removed the code that follows the toast but even that code which queries the web page is not executed in the doinBackground)

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    MyTask(String p) {
        enter=p;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CheckitoutActivity.this,"", "Loading. Please wait...", true);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GHJGFHGJL",1000).show();
         }
    }


     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         progressDialog.dismiss();
     }

}
```

The doInBackground does not apppear to be called. Even the toast is not displayed.Why is that.

Comment: Did you start the Task? Do you have any errors in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not display the UI like toast and dialog alert in doInBackground method. instead you can show these UI in postExecute method of asynkTask

Answer (score 2):

`doInBackground` method is non UI thread so it can't dispaly a toast

So use `runOnUIthread(this)` or `onProgressUpdate` and are sure `.execute()` with 
object, like `objMytask.execute();`

Answer (score 2):

`Toast` (You can't touch UI Thread from doInBack() that's why) is not works in `doInBackground()` so just put Log

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
 try 
 {
  Log.e("AsyncTask","Inside the doInBackground()");
 }
}
```

Now check your `logcat`... If `ProgressDailog` is showing then your `AsyncTask` is works well.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. It appears that the toast was throwing an exception when it was placed inside the doinbackgroung and silently stopping.